# Spring data jpa: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hello everyone I'm new on stackoverflow and new with spring data jpa.

I'm currently developing a personnal website and I have a problem.

I'm using:

Java8
Spring boot 1.5.2
Spring boot starter data jpa 1.5.2 and
MySQL Connector

When I have only one @Entity it's work fine and Hibernate successfuly create MySQL schema but when adding some @Entity with relationship I'm getting this error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at fr.geekads.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ads)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

there is my code structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS03G.png)

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.geekads</groupId>
    <artifactId>geekads</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String email;

    private String pseudo;
    private String password;
    private String avatarURL;
    private String registerDate;
    private String description;
    private String geographicArea;
    private String lastConnexion;

    private Boolean showContact;
    private String skype;
    private String facebook;
    private String twitter;
    private String linkedin;

    private int geekCoins;

    private Project project;
    private List<Ad> ads;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

Project.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String logoUrl;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String description;
    private String projectUrl;

    private Boolean showContact;
    private String skype;
    private String facebook;
    private String twitter;
    private String linkedin;
    private String mail;

    @OneToOne
    private ProjectCategory category;

    @OneToOne
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany
    private List<User> members;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Ad> ads;

    private int geekCoins;
    private int views;
}
```

Comment.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = User.class)
    private User user;

    private String message;
    private String postDate;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Ad.class)
    private Long ad_id;
}
```

And Ad.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ad")
public class Ad {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String logical_id;
    private String title;
    private String logoUrl;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    private AdCategory category;

    private String postDate;
    private String lastUp;

    private Boolean putMoneyIntoPlay;

    private int geekCoins;
    private int views;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    private Project project;

    private Boolean allowComments;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToOne
    private AdType type;

    private String bannerUrl;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
}
```

I do not understand why I'm getting this error... And I am looking for a solution for 2 days...

If you have an idea, Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You have `@OneToOne` on `Ad` but `List<Ad> ads` on `User`. I'm not sure at all this will help, but did you try changing this `@OneToOne` to `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: Does not work but I'm taking a new error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: OneToOne or ManyToOne on fr.geekads.model.User.ads references an unknown entity: java.util.List

Comment: are any of those relations supposed to be bidirectional? in which case put `mappedBy` on all relevant ones. Post your `persistence.xml` so people can see what classes are defined there

Comment: @NeilStockton indeed that was due to my bidirectional relations.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. It was my fault.

**Explanations:**

I was thinking object and not relational database side.

For example in my User.java I was having a relationship to my Ad.java, and in my Ad.java I was having a relationship to my User.java causing a Cartesian product. So Hibernate could not be able to create the SQL schema.

So I refactored my code based on my conceptual data model and it works fine.

Now, User.java no longer references Ad.java and Ad.java references User.java's @id with @OneToOne.

Problem solved ! :)